# Automate Adding Individual Reveal All Mask to Many Layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask, automation, photoshop-scripting

In `Adobe Photoshop CC`, what's a fast way to [add individual default masks (Reveal All)](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) to every layer in a document with a large layer count (say 100 layers)?

I need individual masks, not group masks.

I can manually `ALT+drag` to duplicate a mask to other layers, or simply scroll through selected each layer and then clicking the mask button at the bottom of the `Layers` pane, but I'm trying to create an automated process hence those are not desirable options.

Perhaps there's a script solution to add individual full reveal masks to all open layers?

---

#### Backstory

Per [the workaround here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/94180/97590) to export *en masse* `png-24` images of a common size to `png-8` w/ partial transparency, I'm doing `File` > `Scripts` > `Load Files Into Stack`, selecting all layers, right-clicking on the selection, and lastly choosing `Quick Export as png-8` from the click options menu that comes up.

The only problem is that the `Quick Export as png-8` saves a cropped copy, disregarding the canvas size.  Going individually into `Export As` will work if I manually change the canvas size, but selecting all layers and putting a common canvas size centers the images...

But I've found a way to get the right click `Quick Export...` to respect the canvas position & not crop -- add a 100% fill mask (so all white).  This has no affect on the image other than to preserve the transparent bounding box from cropping upon `Quick Export...` / `Export As`.

However, adding individual masks negates individual time savings.  Hence I need to find a way to add them to each layer quickly (group mask doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create an action with an F key assigned. You still have to tap a key... but it would be faster.

- Highlight the top most layer in the stack
- Create a new Action and assign it an F key, start recording
- Choose `Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal All`
- Hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down and tap the left bracket key (`[`) -- This should highlight the next layer down in the layer stack
- Stop recording the action

Now highlight a layer tap the F key you assigned... and keep tapping until you reach the bottom of the layer stack.

[image]

I'm sure this could be scripted as well, but that's out of my wheelhouse.

Answer (score 1):

I found a script which adds a 'Hide All' layer mask to every layer [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1442459)

So I did a little more digging and figured out how to change it from 'Hide All' to 'Reveal All'.

Here you go:

```
// RevealMask-AllLayers – Adds a 'Reveal All' mask to all layers

#target photoshop

if(app.documents.length>0){
    var docRef = activeDocument;
    var layerNum = docRef.layers.length;

    for(var i=0;i<layerNum;i++){
        docRef.activeLayer = docRef.layers[i];
        if(!docRef.activeLayer.isBackgroundLayer){
            try{addMask ()}
            catch(e){}
            }
        }
    }
else{alert('There are no open files')};

function addMask(){
    var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
        var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idNw = charIDToTypeID( "Nw  " );
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        desc2.putClass( idNw, idChnl );
        var idAt = charIDToTypeID( "At  " );
            var ref1 = new ActionReference();
            var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
            var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
            var idMsk = charIDToTypeID( "Msk " );
            ref1.putEnumerated( idChnl, idChnl, idMsk );
        desc2.putReference( idAt, ref1 );
        var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
        var idUsrM = charIDToTypeID( "UsrM" );
        var idHdAl = charIDToTypeID( "RvlA" );
        desc2.putEnumerated( idUsng, idUsrM, idHdAl );
    executeAction( idMk, desc2, DialogModes.NO );
    }
```